# Epilog in a ListpointPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics

Has Mathematica integrated `Epilog` in `ListPointPlot3D` yet? I have a list of {x,y,z} points, which I am supposed to plot in a 3D space. At the same time I also need to put an Identifier(say Jhon, kay, ross etc) next to each point, the function `Epilog` does in a 2D plot.
Also, is there any workaround? Thank you

Comment: Anyone who did it. why is it downvoted? I am simply asking if this feature has been added and it's not. I have used Mathematica for about 4 years now and I don't think you can do this without an explanation!!! If you can show me how post a solution, or a link to the solution. It's just ridiculous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `LabelingFunction`

```
$VersionNumber
```

> `12`

The data

```
data = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
```

and then you can try

```
ListPointPlot3D[data -> {"John", "Kay", "Ross"}, 
 LabelingFunction -> Center]
```

[image: p1]

Comment: Great! Could you also help me put plot marker along with the label, sphere or a point or anything. I would love with a certain offset

Comment: @Rupesh Sorry but I am not sure I understand what you would like to do. Could you explain more thoroughly with an edit in the OP so I can read? Many thanks.

Comment: Sure, I would want bright red spheres next to Kay, John and Ross. Thank you for helping out.

Comment: @Rupesh oh ok. Thanks for that. Will have a look a bit later :-)

Comment: Thanks, I want a plot marker along with the labelmarker. `ListPointPlot3D[data -> {"John", "Kay", "Ross"}]` which is without the location of labeling function will give a figure but I have no control over the position of kay john or ross.

Comment: @Rupesh I tried various different things from the documentation, but I have not manged to produce what you want. sorry. maybe you can take the `ListPointPlot3D`, create another plot with the `PlotMarkers` and combine the two using `Show`(??)

Comment: no worries, I was thinking the same using show feature. But, for now your solution of `labelfunction` (without specifying the position) works good. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Rupesh glad I was able to help.